# How to check if a string is valid date string or not in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I was trying to check if a string is valid date string or not with below code

```
const isValidDate = (date: any) => {
 return (new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date") && !isNaN(new Date(date));
}
```

For example :

```
let dateStr = "some-random-string-09"
console.log(isValidDate(dateStr)) // returns true instead of false
```

But if I remove the `09` from the string or add some text at the end of the string it returns the expected result.

for Ex:

```
let dateStr = "some-random-string"
console.log(isValidDate(dateStr)) // returns false as expected
```

it is really strange behaviour. Is there a way to validate this particular type of string in TypeScript?

Comment: Besides the ISO8601, what `Date` will accept as input is implementation dependent. Use [tag:regex] to validate input yourself.

Comment: @Amadan—there are two other formats formally supported [*Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse): the formats of *Date.prototype.toString* and *Date.prototype.toUTCString*.

Comment: `new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date")` will always return *true* since the *Date* constructor always returns a *Date* object, which  is always `!==` to a string. OTOH, `new Date(date) != "Invalid Date")` might return *true* or *false*, but is not a reliable way to determine whether a timestamp is valid.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve things like below code:

```
const incorrectDate = Date.parse('01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT 09');
const CorrectDate = Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT');

console.log(incorrectDate );
// expected output: NaN

console.log(CorrectDate );
// expected output: 818035920000
```

So if output is NaN then you can write your business logic

Comment: what about `some-random-string-09` ? because backend is sending something like this.

Comment: if input always contain "-" then you break the string with "-" and check each character.

Comment: ["Parsing of strings with `Date.parse` is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#:~:text=Parsing%20of%20strings%20with%20Date.parse%20is%20strongly%20discouraged)

Comment: Neither example format is supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is entirely implementation dependent and may or may not produce the stated results.